# Who killed Luke's students?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, luke-skywalker, kylo-ren

As we see in The Rise of Kylo Ren comic, it wasn't Ben Solo.

'He vanished with a handful of my students and slaughtered the rest', says Luke to Rey.

But, again, that wasn't Ben; and Luke wasn't conscious when it happened. He didn't really know, although he was certain. Who else could have been?

'Slaughter' sounds like a lightsaber or a knife of some kind. Here (top right hand corner) we see some corpses:
[image]

Already dead. Maybe killed in their sleep.

Comment: i don't recall off the top of my head, but wouldn't it be implied it's the weird villains he's running around w/ in that comic? Secondarily, as it seems the sequel trilogy is wont to do: "it was Palpatine all along"

Comment: How can you say that it wasn't Ben? Didn't Sequel Trilogy address this issue? See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176919/where-did-ben-solo-get-his-red-lighsaber-and-mask-when-attacking-lukes-jedi-sch?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Ben (apparently) killed them. Some of the students did join him, although it's not apparent whether they had any part in the slaughter.

> “He must have thought I was dead,” Luke said. “When I came to, the
> temple was burning. **He had vanished with a handful of my students and
> slaughtered the rest.** Leia blamed Snoke, but it was I who broke that
> family. I failed. Because I was Luke Skywalker, Jedi Master. A
> legend.”
>
> <sub><sup>The Last Jedi - Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

Your confusion likely stems from the fact that the comic doesn't portray these events as was described in the film. Multiple tweets on the issue are referenced [here](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Destruction_of_the_Jedi_Temple#cite_note-Twitter_MM_TROKR_misinterpretation-49)

Comment: What confusion? Luke thought it had been Ben: but we don't see it. Common sense says 'innocent until proven otherwise' (and that was Luke's sin in the hut: 'you failed by thinking his choice was made'). So, Ben didn't do it. He, as Kylo, killed Han. We know that to be true. The students are a different thing. No matter what Luke thought. (Similarly, Ben didn't vanish *with* a 'handful' of students: Ben vanished, followed by 3 of them. That's in the comic. Are 3 a 'handful', or less than that?) So, the film and the comic would be in fact complementary, and not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Sunsetguy6776 - Since when was Ben Solo capable of calling down destructive lightning?

Comment: He didn't call down destructive lightning. Just like he didn't start what looks like a fire immediately before the lightning (in the comic above, the panel with all that smoke and him saying 'w-what?')

Comment: This trope has also been used in a similarly confusing manner Re: Obi-Wan telling Luke that Vader killed his Father.